# android studio settings androidannotations

Tags: android, android-studio, settings, android-annotations

I wanna enable android annotations processor in my application. I was wondering that i couldn't find  Settings > Compiler > Annotation Processing in my project in android studio. If i open other projects in android studio there is a compiler item and i can enable it. Please give me a reason why compiler item is not appearing???

```
System.out.printLn("Thanks in advance!");
```

Here is my settings:

[image]

Comment: Gradle based project?

Comment: yes, it`s gradle project

Comment: Have you seen this http://www.jayway.com/2014/02/21/androidannotations-setup-in-android-studio/ and original here https://bitbucket.org/hvisser/android-apt

Comment: Sure i`ve seen all of them! :))))

Comment: Please read [this](https://github.com/excilys/androidannotations/wiki/Building-Project-Gradle).